# To update a row in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In the below grid view i want to update a row . I tried but i couldn't make it. pls help me to do this.

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" runat="server" ID="srchgrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" ShowFooter="false" 
                  PageSize-Mode="NumericPages" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-Visible="true" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"  
        OnRowCommand="srchgrid_RowCommand" RowUpdating="srchgrid_RowUpdating"
                    CssClass="mGrid"
                    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" itemstyle-width="150px">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" RowIndex="Edit" Text="Edit"  CausesValidation="false"/>

                            </ItemTemplate>
```

```
 protected void srchgrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

                if (e.RowIndex.Equals("Edit"))
                {

                    LinkButton btnView = (LinkButton)srchgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("btnView"); 
}}
```

Comment: Hint : `e.RowIndex` is `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Add **Cells[*Cell_No*]**

```
LinkButton btnView = (LinkButton)srchgrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Cell_No].FindControl("btnView");
```